# How to show only specific a view in Forge Autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Its been a couple of days I had been working on Forge Api of Autodesk and I am doing well with my implementation as per requirement recently I am trying to render a specific / single view
Example - I am having a RVT file which renders a building with 4 rooms now my issue is there are 4 people and I want to only show one room to each of this people so Room A to Person A, Room B to Person B and so On, Room B should not be visible to person A.

In short I dont want to render the whole model I am only interested in rendering few model inside a parent model

I had been going to the documentation and I could not find much help from it so can some one guide me over it or could refer me a right place in the documentation which I could use to implement above scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically handled at the design level, for example, by [hiding elements in specific views in Revit](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/RevitLT-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-B056FB7C-084E-4580-86A9-5735EA92CB7C-htm.html).

The Forge Viewer *can* help a bit, though: if you know the dbIDs of the objects you want to filter, you can pass them into the [loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) method like this:

```
// Include the dbIDs of the elements you want to load in the `options.ids` array
const options = { ids: [123, 456] };
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, node, options);
```

Comment: I am still confused and was not able to get the desired result, I am trying to reproduce my scenario in this sample project https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample, considering this sample can u please help me how can I show only motor of shaver in the viewer ? @Petr Broz